# How to Improve SharePoint 2010 site performance , page load time etc?

Tags: web-part, performance, optimization

I'm using sharepoint 2010 site. I want to improve site performance in list, page librarys, web parts, page load time. Please suggest what are all the possible ways to optimize site performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question will not lead to any specific answer as its scope is too wide.

First of all you need to know the cause of your problem. So [5 Reasons Why You Have SharePoint Performance Issues](https://web.archive.org/web/20170923151516/http://sharepointpromag.com:80/blog/5-reasons-why-you-have-sharepoint-performance-issues)  is the great article which describe why we face performance issue in SharePoint. Please look it once.

There are so many criteria on which performance depends. Some of the performance criteria are listed [Improving SharePoint Performance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd776503%28v=msdn.10%29).

**Benjamin Niaulin** describes a very nice way to improve the performance of SharePoint. He has considered following points into consideration.

- The performance of SharePoint is directly linked to SQL Server
- The Disks and the NTFS Allocation size
- Modifying the Model Database to increase SharePoint performance
- Instant File Initialization can help speed up SharePoint but be careful
- Logs and Maintenance of your SharePoint
- The famous SharePoint Continuous Crawl for Search
- A case of the SharePoint Service Applications
- SharePoint isn’t just database, it’s also a lot of IIS

You can find detail from [What I did to improve my SharePoint Performance: by Benjamin Niaulin](https://sharegate.com/blog/improving-sharepoint-performance)

Performance of a SharePoint application requires a lot of attention to the small components. Until and unless you are not focusing on small components of the SharePoint you will always fail in achieving your goal of performance.

Some of the components are :

- **WebParts** : If you are using WebParts then you have to think of WebPart's performance as well. Refer [5 Tips to Improve SharePoint Web Part Performance](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220023117/http://apmblog.dynatrace.com:80/2015/03/24/5-tips-to-improve-sharepoint-web-part-performance/) for WebPart performance.
- **Your custom solution deployed** : If you have deployed your custom solution then you can also take a look to your custom codes.
- **JS Libraries** : If you have used lots of JS then it will also decrease your performance for loading time as for every JS file a different HTTP call be done. For avoiding this you can use the concept of **Bundling and Minification**
- **Cache** : Use maximum of your cache. This will step up in performance to some extends. You can find a good article on SharePoint Caching from [Improving the Performance of your SharePoint sites](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/improving-performance-of-sharepoint-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CDN Links for Jquery and Bootstrap(If you are using)

Make use of cache to store files in the clients browser.